# webscraping, beautiful soup - scrape the author in a small class and passing parameters to render on the html

Tags: flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I am trying to use flask/beautiful soup to scrape the AUTHOR from: http://quotes.toscrape.com/

I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
source=requests.get('http://quotes.toscrape.com/').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
#title=soup.find('title')
quote=soup.find('div',class_='quote')
quotetext=quote.span.text

author=soup.find('div',class_='author')
authortext=author.a.text
```

Also, I am trying to pass two variables to the html page and render them using jinja, like this (see below) is that allowed and valid?

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html',quotetext=quotetext,authortext=authortext)
```

The html for the .html page above is:

```
<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
        <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
        </span>
```

I want to get at the author part and render Albert-Einstein to the screen, and also use {{quotes}} to render the quotes as well, like below on home.html

```
 <h1>Scraping Stuff</h1>
    <p>{{quotetext}}</p>
    <p>{{authortext}}</p>
```

Any suggestions and a fix to the above code appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    quotes = [q.text for q in soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'text' )]

    authors = [a.text for a in soup.find_all('small', class_ = 'author' )]

for q, a in zip(quotes, authors):
    print (q, 'by:', a)


“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
By: Albert Einstein
“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.” 
By: J.K. Rowling
“There are only two ways to 
live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as 
though everything is a miracle.” 
By: Albert Einstein
“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.” 
By: Jane Austen
“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.” 
By: Marilyn Monroe
“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.” 
By: Albert Einstein
“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.” 
By: André Gide
“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.” 
By: Thomas A. Edison
“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.” 
By: Eleanor Roosevelt
“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.” 
By: Steve Martin
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try this shortly. Are you able to also answer the jinja part of the question. Is this method of passing two variables to the html valid? render_template('home.html',quotetext=quotetext,authortext=authortext)

Comment: @MissComputing, you're wlecome. I don't know anything about jinja. :)

Comment: Any chance you could also use your brain on this ....:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62705461/beautiful-soup-attempt-to-scrape-a-specific-integer-variable-and-display-it-on